# How to create autocompletion feature?

Tags: c#, text-editor

I would like to create the autocompletion(intellisense) feature in an editor I'm
working on. Basically the keywords
preceeding the . (period) to invoke the autocompletion box will be user
defined. i've created the editor using visual c#. Now i need to create an autocompletion box.

can any one help me to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Intellisense term is a registered trademark of Microsoft Co. Better call your feature autocompletion or sth like that.

Comment: Before doing such a big task you may evaluate some libraries that already do that: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following site may help you along with sample code :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/JGIntelli.aspx